# What's 'paying through the nose/ mean?

Tags: expressions

Where does 'pay through the nose' come from?

Comment: I pasted the exact text of your question into google which gave me a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's an idiom meaning you pay not the normal price but considerably more.
See TFD 
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+through+the+nose

As to your second question about the origin there seems to be no accepted explanation. Etymonline only has a guess:

Pay through the nose (1670s) seems to suggest "bleed."

Comment: A favorite story: a private (fee-paying) school once informed all parents that fees had to be increased by £500 per annum. Unfortunately the letter was sent out with only one 'n' in 'annum'. One parent replied that he would prefer to go on paying 'through the nose' like he'd always done in the past.